# How to fix 'NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder'

Tags: java, ssl, zendesk-api

I work on an application that connects to an external API (Zendesk API) using SSL.

It used to work fine, but now whenever the application tries to connect to Zendesk API, we get following error: `java.net.ConnectException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)` caused by `NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder`.

We use Java 1.7.0_231 on Debian 8.11.

I couldn't find any solution on the internet.

I've checked the credentials : they are correct.

From what I've found on the internet this error can be caused by a missing jar "jsse.jar" but I've checked and it is present.

It works fine on another environment, a Debian 9.9 with java 1.7.0_211.

This is the stack trace :

```
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.future.NettyResponseFuture.abort(NettyResponseFuture.java:231)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyConnectListener.onFutureFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:137)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:145)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:409)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.addListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:145)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.sendRequestWithNewChannel(NettyRequestSender.java:284)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.sendRequestWithCertainForceConnect(NettyRequestSender.java:142)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.sendRequest(NettyRequestSender.java:117)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:87)
    at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:506)
    at org.zendesk.client.v2.Zendesk.submit(Zendesk.java:1771)
    at org.zendesk.client.v2.Zendesk.access$1300(Zendesk.java:91)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyConnectListener.onFutureFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:133)
    ... 100 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1256)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:97)
    at com.ning.http.util.SslUtils.getSSLContext(SslUtils.java:70)
    at com.ning.http.client.SSLEngineFactory$DefaultSSLEngineFactory.newSSLEngine(SSLEngineFactory.java:49)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.channel.ChannelManager.createSslHandler(ChannelManager.java:401)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.channel.SslInitializer.connectRequested(SslInitializer.java:44)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelDownstreamHandler.handleDownstream(SimpleChannelDownstreamHandler.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleDownstream(HttpClientCodec.java:97)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleDownstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:109)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:634)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:216)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:229)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:182)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.connect(NettyRequestSender.java:377)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.sendRequestWithNewChannel(NettyRequestSender.java:283)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:1006)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor559.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1237)
    ... 120 more
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was introduced in a recent update of the debian package of openjdk, version 7u231-2.6.19-1~deb8u1.
It was fixed in version 7u231-2.6.19-1~deb8u2.

See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=935082.